# Angular/NodeJS: Unable to upload image to AWS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, input

I have a Node/Express application and attempting to retrieve file information for upload from an Angular/Ionic front end. I created a separate Service on Angular to get the Image name which works. My real problem is getting the file itself and uploading it to the server from Angular. How would I get the image file for uploading from the Angular front end side?

Below is my code:

```
<div class="item-input"> 
 <!--list item-->  
 <div data-ng-repeat="user in users"> 

    Username: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the event name" name="username" ng-model="user.username" required> 

    Password: <input type="password" placeholder="Enter the password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" required> 

    <!--more items that I will omit from this--> 
    Profile Image: 
    <div ng-if="user.imageurl">
       {{ user.imageurl }}
       <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="removepropic()">Remove Image
       </button>d
      <div ng-repeat="step in stepsModel">
         <img class="thumb" ng-src="{{ step }}" style="width:100px; height:100px" />
      </div>

      <input type="file" ng-model-instant onchange="angular.element(this).scope().imageUpload(this)" /> 
    </div> 

    <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="editprofile(user)">
     Edit Account
    </button>

    <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="deleteprofile()">
     Delete Account
    </button>

 </div>
```

Controller JS file

```
.controller('ProfileUpdateCtrl', function($http, $state, $http, $cordovaOauth, $stateParams, $rootScope, $scope, UserFac, UploadFac) {  

id = $stateParams.id;    

$scope.user = {}; 

UserFac.getUser(id).success(function(data) {  
   $scope.users = data; 
}); 

$scope.editprofile = function(user) {  

   username = user.username;  
   password = user.password; 
   firstname = user.firstname; 
   lastname = user.lastname; 
   birthday = user.birthday;
   hometown = user.hometown;  
   email = user.email;   


   mark = { hometown: hometown, username: username, password:password, email:email, firstname:firstname, lastname:lastname,birthday:birthday }; 

   setmark = angular.toJson(mark);   

   UserFac.updateUser(id, setmark); 

   //reload to current controller 
   $state.reload({'reload':true});


}

//Remove Profile Image from Database. 
$scope.removepropic = function(user) { 

  blank = []; 

  mark = { imageurl:blank }; 
  setmark = angular.toJson(mark); 
  UserFac.updateUser(id, setmark);  
}

//Image Uploading 
$scope.stepsModel = [];

$scope.imageUpload = function(element) { 

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);  

    file = element.files[0]; 

    mark = { imageurl:element.files[0].name }; 
    setmark = angular.toJson(mark); 

    //upload image to AWS 
    UploadFac.sendImg(file); 

    //send information to database
    UserFac.updateUser(id, setmark); 

    console.log(element.files[0]);   
}

//Terminate Profile
$scope.deleteprofile = function() { 
   UserFac.deleteUser(id); 
   $state.go('home'); 
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great and simple solution for uploading files to your server or directly from the browser to S3.  In the later case you can use your server to pass tokens you request from AWS to your user to give them temporary privileges to upload.

http://fineuploader.com/

You can quickly integrate their UI into your site, or create a custom UI. It is powerful and has many built in features plus good documentation.  By using Amazon S3 feature to upload directly from the browser, you eliminate a lot of overhead from your server processing the files during upload.

Answer (score 0):

i am using image upload in **AWS** using **REST API** review the code in server side [view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252759/cordova-ionic-app-uploading-base64-image-to-s3-via-server-signed-url/35363402#35363402)

and client side view [show client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297497/ionic-upload-image-to-server/33690634#33690634)